# Android MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264 encoder type

Tags: android, mediarecorder, encoder

MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264 in snapdragon 805 is using Hardware Encoder(OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc) or Software Encoder?

Answer (score 1):

Snapdragon 805 supports h.264 hardware encode.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. But that i have already know. But i want to know that  how can i use hardware encoding? If i use [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) and recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264); will it use hardware or software encoder? Because in some other post i found that OMX hardware encoder can be use by using [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)?

Comment: MediaRecorder and MediaCodec both support hardware and software encode. If a hardware encoder exists, Android will use hardware before software. Since the Snapdragon 805 supports h.264 hardware encode, you will get hardware when you request H.264. On other devices, this may not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.. Can you tell me which MediaRecorder or MediaCodec is more efficient for 1080p 60fps video encoding using OMX hardware encoding in terms of the low latency?

Comment: MediaRecorder and MediaCodec are both high level wrappers around the native level Stagefright media engine, which deals directly with the OpenMax codecs. MediaRecorder and MediaCodec will use the same encoders and decoders. You want to chose the right H.264 encoder profile for low-latency which is most likely the Baseline profile (single pass no B-frames) and is probably the only encoder you have available since many Android devices do not support Main or High profiles (multi-pass with or without B-frames).